# PHP timeout is zero and memory limit is 1024M and script timeout?

Tags: php, php.ini

on my work server i set PHP settings to be 1024M memory limit and max execution time to zero
after all this the script still timeout  !!
what are other options to make script runs forever if i want
thanks in advance.

Comment: Running a script from a browser or cli?

Comment: i run it from browser.

Comment: you're probably running into the limit on your http server.

Comment: what http settings exactly you mean

Comment: beats me, what http server are you using. if you dont know, its probably apache. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629566/how-to-increase-apache-timeout-directive-in-htaccess

Comment: it is apache actually so only apache timeout for running

Comment: i change apache timeout and still script timeout even earlier than before

Comment: i've done the above settings for php and apache ans still the script is timeout

Comment: Ive helped you as much as I can, someone else should be along soon to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen FastCGI and/or PHP-FPM have a timeout where it killed scripts after a certain amount of execution time.  If you're using one of those you could look into the settings for that.

Comment: the server actually using fastcgi i will check the docs and search to see configurations

Comment: @user2381778 I hope you were able to get your issue resolved.  If my answer was helpful to you, I'd appreciate if you could mark it as accepted so I can get credit for it.  Thanks